# Allowing downloads from a remote server only when logged in on separate server hosting the site

Tags: php, apache

We're close to launching a new project of ours but we're at the last hurdle. We have a dedicated file server that will be serving all of our downloads, however at the moment it's showing the download directories to any visitor to the site. We're wanting to have it so that the downloads only show (it's a simple system that simple embeds a file directory listing within our page, but does the job for us) when the visitor is logged in. How would we go about doing this with Apache?

This is pretty much the last bit we need to work on, so any help is gratefully received!

Additional information can be given if needed, I understand I may have been slightly vague, however I'm not the developer of the project, I'm simply the PR / friendly face!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Include `Options -Indexes` in your apache .htaccess or httpd.conf for every folder.
2. Create a subdomain for the url and link the file server to it
3. Create a PHP script on the file server that fetches and downloads the correct file
4. At the link level (when user wants to download) include link subdomain.site.com/download.php or similar

This will mask the file server and its contents, while allowing for the downloading of the files.